# Why is print('\a') not working in my python code?

Tags: python, printing

I am writing some code in a standard python 3.8 shell and I want to `print('\a')` which plays a ding sound on your computer. This works in a thonny python shell but will not work in any other python shell. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I just tried this and it worked just fine on a Windows 10 laptop running python 3.8.  I tried researching this problem but did not find anything related to it; are you sure it's not a speaker issue?

Comment: Works for me in Windows Powershell...

Answer (score 2):

Printing '\a' is not supported by IDLE. (I think that '\r' and '\b' also do not work properly.)